# Custom web templates vs custom site definitions

Tags: site-definition, web-template

I read the MSDN article ["Deciding between custom web templates and custom site definitions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979683.aspx). The article only scratches the surface, so I was wondering if anyone have had some hands on experience with web templates.

Im thinking pros and cons. An obvious one would be that its in the sandbox and hence easier to get deployed.

Also what would be typical scenarios for prefering web templates over site definitions?

Let me hear your thoughts. I marked the Q community wiki since i expect (hope for?) several answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best article as of now on this subject is Vesa Juvonens post [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119071517/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice article on SharePointDevWiki last night that was useful:
http://sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Site+Features+vs+Site+Templates+vs+Site+Definitions

There are a few pros and cons, some interesting feedback and some great external resource links -- including this list of pros and cons: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brianwilson/site-definitions-versus-site-templates-and-deciding-on-the-correct-customization-approach)

I hope more people respond.  It would be nice to have a master list as an outcome of this.

Comment: I think i was a bit unclear in the subject. I am talking about the new WebTemplate features. I just read a good article on the subject by Mirjam http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/06/15/site-definitions-vs.-webtemplates.aspx

Comment: My bad, Anders.  That's a nice post.  Thanks for sharing.  I agree with Joel's comments that it would be nice if someone would put together a Hands on Lab that started with the business requirements and walked the learner through creating the template.  What would be even more cool is if said lab walked the learner through making a change to that template once it is deployed.  Once I understand them well enough, I may give it a go if no one else has done it.

Comment: i couldnt agree more. upgrade scenarios is always where you hit your head hard in sharepoint